# Catching a framework exception

Tags: vb.net

I'm having some trouble catching and handling an exception. 
My (simplified) application has a picturebox which shows a live video feed from a connected webcam. I'm using the Metrilius Metricam SDK (http://www.metrilus.de/blog/portfolio-items/metricam/) to connect to the webcam.
Using a backgroundworker, I am calling the camera.update function, grabbing the bitmap and setting the picturebox to it. Whenever the user hits Enter, the current frame is grabbed and stored.
As mentioned earlier, an exception is thrown at completely random points in time when the picturebox is being updated with the latest bmp from the camera. As you can see in the code below, I have wrapped the assignment in a try/catch block but it isn't catching it. What could I do to handle this gracefully? The exception draws a big red X on the picturebox and the program has to be closed and restarted. 
The picturebox's sizemode property is set to Zoom.

Code below:

```
Private Sub BG1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BG1.DoWork
    While Not BG1.CancellationPending

        If pauseCamUpdate = False Then 'PausecamUpdate is a flag that is set to False during calls to store the current frame
            i += 1
            If i Mod 2 = 0 Then Continue While 'Dropping every nth frame to make the update smoother
            If i > 10000 Then
                i = 0
            End If
            Try
                activeCam.Update()
                pictPhoto.Image = CType(CType(activeCam, WebCam).CalcBitmap(), Bitmap)
                'pictPhoto.Invalidate()
                 Application.DoEvents()
            Catch exp As Exception 
            End Try
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

The exception text minus the loaded assemblies:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

**System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.**
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Height()
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
at 

System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, 
Int16 layer)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr 
wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: You need to learn how to use a `BackgroundWorker`. The whole point is background work. Anything to do with the UI is inherently foreground work, so not to be done in the `DoWork` event handler.  Read the documentation for the class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The SDK example uses a background worker to keep the image updated, so I followed that. Is  there any way I can trap this exception?

Comment: You don't update the UI in the `DoWork` event handler. If you have an example that does then it's a bad example. Read up on how to use a `BackgroundWorker` properly and then you can probably avoid the exception. Don't wait for the information to come to you. Go to it. VS has a Help menu for a reason.